# Data association within a service oriented architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, architecture

We have 3 API applications build as a sort of service oriented architecture. I say *sort of* because it does not totally embrace the SOA tenets as I'm about to explain with this simple use case.

### Use case

We have a **Client API** which is responsible for handling clients contact information. On the other end, we have a **Sales API** which take care of quotation and billing. This is the part when it becomes messy (IMHO). The sales API has an *orders* table which has a **client_id** attribute in order to know which client is associated to it.

### Problem

As I said, the architecture has been built as a sort of SOA, meaning that each service has it's own database.
So to continue with our use case, the sales API is storing at some point a **client_id**, client that does not actually exists in the context of this API because the Client API is the one holding this responsability.

For example, let's say that in order to create a new sales' order, I need to check that the associated client (send as client_id in a POST api.sales.domain.com/orders) actually exists. How to handle such case? For now we do a HTTP request against the Client API and check for a 200 response.
What if we want to return embbed client data within an order json:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "status": "pending",
    "client": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address": "123 street"
    }
}
```

As we are using Rails, we use the gem Her in order kinda deal with these cases. But it does not really feel right.

is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First why are you allowing to create a client_id in Sales API system, which does not exist in Client API system? When you add a record in Sales API system, simultaneously it should add the client_id in Client API system, which does not arise this problem itself. And every time you need not check for the existence of client_id in Client API. I think this is the best way.

If you cannot follow the above approach then your solution is one way to implement it.